# Unable to retract Very Low Quality flag

Tags: bug, flags, low-quality-posts, retracted-flags

I flagged an answer yesterday as VLQ (Very Low Quality). Since then, it has been accepted by the OP. After reading it again, it appears borderline, and I don't want to eat a declined flag, so I attempted to retract the flag. Because VLQ is not a choice (I'm guessing because it's been accepted or upvoted, and no longer able to acquire future VLQ flags, that the choice is unavailable.) Can you allow users to retract these types of flags?

[This is the post in question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229500/using-angularjs-with-npm/39229588#39229588)

[image]

Comment: I don't think has anything to do with the answer being accepted. VQ is not available on positively scored posts, that's probably what is preventing it from showing.

Comment: Cross-meta duplicate: [Do not hide VLQ flag option from users who already flagged and may wish to retract](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283357/do-not-hide-vlq-flag-option-from-users-who-already-flagged-and-may-wish-to-retra)

Answer (score 10):

[Samuel Liew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) [created](https://stackapps.com/questions/7033/retract-flags-from-the-flagged-posts-for-user-page#comment17829_7033) a new userscript, [Flag Retractor](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/FlagRetractor.user.js) <sup>([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/FlagRetractor.user.js))</sup>, which allows you to retract flags from your "[Pending All flags raised](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current?status=1)" page.