# Why can I put two flags on one question at the same time?

Tags: discussion, flags

When reviewing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222360/is-anyone-here-have-code-for-multiple-inline-insert-on-laravel-5-4-such-as-multi) I initially flagged it as Very Low Quality. I thought about it for a few minutes and then realized it would probably be better as an off topic opinion based flag because the OP was asking for a tutorial. When I went to retract the VLQ flag, I didn't have the option to, so I entered the off topic flag.

When I looked at my flag summary, it had both flags listed as pending. Why am I allowed to put multiple flags on the same question at the same time, and why am I not allowed to withdraw VLQ flags?

Comment: I'd assume it's because those two flags fit in two separate categories. One is a moderator flag, the other is a closure flag. Once you're above a certain amount of rep, you'll no longer be able to cast closure flags and instead will cast closure votes.

Comment: FYI - There's also an off-topic flag for asking for off-site resources, such as tutorials. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @KevinB Neither are moderator flags.

Comment: @silencedmessage Yeah, that's the second flag that I cast (you get to it from the "Should Be Closed -> Off Topic" menu). It just didn't occur to me until after I had cast the VLQ flag, and then I couldn't withdraw VLQ.

Comment: Ah.  In your post it says "off topic opinion based", I thought you meant the "primarily opinion-based" flag.

Comment: related: [Do not hide VLQ flag option from users who already flagged and may wish to retract](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283357/165773) at MSE and [Unable to retract VLQ flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333569/839601) here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an oddity in the availability of the VLQ flag and how our system handles that case. The question is currently in the Triage review queue, which means the VLQ flag is not allowed to be cast and is hidden from the flag dialog altogether (the option is also unavailable for questions currently in the Close Votes queue). That causes two problems in your situation:

1. Since it's not shown as an option, you can't retract it.
2. Since it wasn't loaded, the system isn't aware that you have a pending VLQ flag - it didn't look for it. So it lets you add another flag not realizing you have a pending one.

It might be possible that there's something we could do to handle this situation better. It's also possible that it's too much effort and that's why it was implemented this way in the first place.

Comment: Even if it *did* know that you had a pending VLQ flag, it would still let you cast other types of flags, just not more VLQ flags.  You can't have more than one (non-moderator) flag *of a single type* cast for a post.

Comment: @Servy You can only cast one flag of a particular type *ever* (excluding other) on a post, but you can also only have one *pending* per post at a given time. At least, you're supposed to only have one pending.