# Cannot retract flag: what can be the reason?

Tags: support, bug, flags

I flagged a post whose quality was terrible, but the user improved it, so I decided to retract the pending flag:

[image]

However, when I go on the post, there isn't the option to retract it:

[image]

What could be the reason? Is it a bug?

Comment: @GinoMempin it was a `Very Low Quality` flag on a question

Comment: I can confirm there's a currently pending VLQ flag on a question; not sure why it can't be retracted though. Might be some weird behavior related to VLQ question flagging mechanics?

Comment: That said, on the question I'm seeing, I'm also not seeing any edits made; are you sure you're on the right question?

Comment: If the flag is still pending then is it the same as this? [Unable to retract VLQ flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333569/2745495) (which is saying that it's "by-design" right now and there's a feature request on meta SE to allow retracting pending VLQ flags)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine you're right my bad, was looking at the wrong post: the post I'm looking at wasn't edited. However I still see `pending` in my flags list and cannot still retract it...

Comment: Looks like it. I compared to a new post where the VLQ option is present; the VLQ flag option has disappeared since the flag in question was raised, presumably because of the post's age (it's >1 hour old now, though I'm not sure what the thresholds are). Assuming the question I found is correct, it's chilling at a solid -3, and has for a while, so it isn't vote related.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine exactly, that's the question involved, -3 and has been edited just  3 mins ago